# Style a banner using transform: rotateZ() and ::after pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add some pizzazz to some banners... my banners are simply an h1 element with a background color property that stretches the legth of the containing element.

**Here is my CSS:**

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 20px;
}

.banner-blue {
    background-color: #93DEFF;
    color: #222222;
}

.banner-yellow {
    background-color: #FFF072;
    color: #777777;
}

.banner-red {
    background-color: #FF356B;
    color: white;
}
```

And I would apply it like this:

```
<h1 class="banner banner-yellow">I'm a banner!</h1>
```

**My problem:**

I want to overlay a copy of the banner background but change the color and rotate it slightly on the z-axis to get an effect like this.

[image]

However I can't work out how to do that using the ::before (or is it ::after) psuedo-elements to do that... here is what I have tried:

```
.banner-red::before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(255,30,60,0.4);
    transform: rotateZ(3deg);
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Here is a codepen of it running: not looking too good: https://codepen.io/jethazelhurst/pen/JyKqRB

Comment: I can't find the problem.

Comment: Looks to me like you already done this, just not exactly the same as the representational pic above. This any closer to what you want? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeLrjN

Comment: There are two possibilities :
- You want this effect to be a static background effect : you should just create a picture like the one you shown and add it as a background-image.
- You want this effect to be an animation (on hover for example) then it is possible to create it with CSS (@OleHaugset did it perfectly)
But what is the usage of this effect ?

Comment: @Louis it's just to learn more about the psuedo-element and I thought I could avoid creating images when I could effectively create the same thing with some CSS.

Comment: @Ole Haugset, it looks great! Just one problem, it looks like the white text is underneath the pseuto-element?

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst updated my codepen. As someone answered below, you can add the text in a span element and use z-index to define the position of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rotate your box in the opposite direction: `transform: rotateZ(-3deg);`

You can set the `top` and `left` value in order to place your rotated box correctly.

```
.banner-red::before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(255,30,60,0.4);
    transform: rotateZ(-3deg);
    width: 102%;
    height: 97px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Of course you can change the colors: your horizontal box is `#91c6ff` and the rotated one is `#91c6ff`. Also, they are transparent.

Here's a fork of your project: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdBVGe

And with the colors:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a element with another child element for text, `span` for example. Then you can set `z-index` on span so that text is above pseudo element.

```css
div {
  background: #91C6FF;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(135, 171, 255, 0.7);
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't the solution above slighty cleaner? Or are there advantages to using a parent like this?